# Working with bar charts in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to have bars of different colour? 
Basic example:

```
    x=[1,2,3,4,5]
    y=[1,2,2,3,10]
    figure()
    plt.bar(x,y)
```

I get a basic bar chart with blue bars. Is there a way to colour one bar a different colour?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 2, 2, 3, 10]
b = plt.bar(x, y)
b[0].set_color('r')
plt.show()
```

That will give you one red bar at the start:

[image]

Comment: can I specify what bar exactly to colour? With the largest y value or smallest?

Comment: you can select any bar you like, `b[-1].set_color('r')` will set the last, if you want to select the smallest just use min/max to get the index of the smallest/largest  value `b[max(enumerate(y),key=lambda x:x[1])[0]].set_color('r')`, if you are using numpy arrays it will obviously be different to get the min/max but the logic is the same

Answer (score 1):

there is probably a way to do exactly what you want ... but couldnt you just do

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[1,2,0,3,10]
figure()
plt.bar(x,y)
y2 = [0,0,4,0,0]
plt.bar(x,y2,style="b")
```

Comment: For some reason it took me literally 18 hours to figure out your answer. But that's a really simple solution. Thanks!